# Stream multiple files in _one_ ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

What is best practice to stream multiple files in **one** ASIHTTPRequest?

Right now, for one file I use:

```
....
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:someUrl];
[request setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
[request appendPostDataFromFile:someFilePath];
[request startSynchronous];
```

How to stream multiple files without placing all files in memory before transmission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ASIFormDataRequest** might be the better choice in this case. With this a multipart POST can be accomplished:

```
...
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
[request setFile:someFilePath forKey:@"file1"];
[request setFile:someOtherFilePath forKey:@"file2"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```